# How to reset authentication token right after user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

In ActiveAdmin, when I create a new user (not an admin user) and then check in the console, the authentication_token is nil.  I need to manually issue reset_authencation_token! on the user so he can connect.
How can I populate this token right after the user is created ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
before_save :ensure_authentication_token
```

Add this to your User model. You don't have to use `before_save` any similar hook will do.